# Block functions from library from being used?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm working on a project with others and they keep calling ArrayList.add() without doing checks that are critical to the program, so I'm wondering is there a way to block use of the .add() method without removing it from the library.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe teach them what they have to check before calling add ? IMO the solution is not to restrict some API methods because they don't use them well, but rather teach them how you want them to use it.

Comment: Use a subclass or a class that composites. In general, no.

Comment: Don't expose your `ArrayList`?

Comment: @DaveNewton this is not true, by AOP you can effectively hide whatever method you have and also check it on build time.

Comment: @kulatamicuda ... So, in general, no. If the OP is asking the question clearly they're not at the point AOP is a realistic option. Either way, AOP is not "in general". I also don't think adding aspects around default JDK library functionality that changes behavior in this way is a great idea--better to wrap it up in your application.

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far I understand teaching them is the best way but it's proving a problem having explained it many times, wrapping it in a List is a nice solution although they have access to all the code so theres not much to stop them just calling list.add(o). I will look into AOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expose a simple subclass of ArrayList through your API. Override the specific methods, including your checks. e.g.

```
public class MyList<E> extends ArrayList<E>
{

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e)
    {

        if (!checkInput())
        {
            throw new UnexpectedInputException();
        }
        return super.add(e);
    }

    private boolean checkInput()
    {
        // Really check the input!
        return false;
    }

}
```

This will throw an exception if the input fails your checks.

```
List<String> list = new MyList<>();
list.add("myString"); // Throws exception
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a new class that wraps a List and does all the checks for you

```
MyList{

  private List list;

  public void checkThenAdd(Object o){
    //do checks here throw Exception if problem
    //if pass THEN add
    list.add(o);
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to name the method `add` like in list? From the clients perspective you dont really care if he does the checks when is't a void.

Comment: @RobertNiestroj maybe. It depends what how the programmer wants the API to do.  If it's just hiding the checks then yes but if it's a different class that's part of the domain, then no.